# Worrisome oembed hits

Tags: oembed

I'm getting oembed hits to my wordpress site that look like some kind of hacking attempts. Here's an example:

```
/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2FMySite.com%2Fprivacy%2F&format=xml&Hmjy%3D2697%20AND%201%3D1%20UNION%20ALL%20SELECT%201%2CNULL%2C%27%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22XSS%22%29%3C%2Fscript%3E%27%2Ctable_name%20FROM%20information_schema.tables%20WHERE%202%3E1--%2F%2A%2A%2F%3B%20EXEC%20xp_cmdshell%28%27cat%20..%2F..%2F..%2Fetc%2Fpasswd%27%29%23
```

I haven't had any success searching for information about this (and I'm not sure exactly what to search on). Could somebody point me in the right direction?